# Replace R column values

Tags: r, replace, dataframe

I screwed up entering survey data into a data frame, and I have a column with values P, G, S, and N. I need to replace P with 1, G with 2, S with 3 and N with 4.

`df1$type <- replace(as.numeric(df1$type), df1$type == "P", "1")`

I tried using this, but this affects all the values not just P.

How do I replace each value individually? P, G, S, and N are arranged randomly so I can't just fill it with a repeating column of 1, 2, 3, 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
df1$type <- as.numeric(factor(df1$type, levels=c("P","G","S","N")))
```

factor variables in R automatically assign an integer to each level. By using as.numeric(), you can extract that integer value (just make sure you have your levels in the right order).